# Android app works on WiFi, in debug mode, or on emulator, not on cell network

Tags: android, android-emulator, html-parsing, android-asynctask

I have an android application that parses some HTML, downloads an image, and displays it. I'm using an `AsyncTask` to do the HTML parsing and image downloading, but that shouldn't be relevant. I never have a problem when I'm on WiFi on my phone, when I'm using the Eclipse debugger on my phone, or when I'm using the emulator. When I have my phone on the cell network (even with pretty good reception), the image sometimes fails to display.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what is wrong, since the problem cannot be reproduced in the debugger. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks!

**Update:** I have narrowed it down to the image downloading function. This way my original code:

```
private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap image = null;
        debug = "";
        try {
            URL image_url = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection image_connection = (HttpURLConnection) image_url
                    .openConnection();
            image_connection.connect();
            InputStream image_stream = image_connection.getInputStream();
            debug = image_stream.available()+"";
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("downloadImage", "Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }

        return image;
}
```

I have also tried using the code from this tutorial, but the same bug showed up.

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39810/1954

At this point I think it must have to do with Verizon, but I'm not sure how to figure out what's going on. I wish there was something like Wireshark for Android. I've given my code to a friend of mine on T-Mobile with the G1 and a friend on Sprint with the EVO. I have the Droid Eris on Verizon.

Comment: At all does it transfers some data? Mobile connections use some kind of proxys, maybe you should check your server logs to get more info.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not my server I'm accessing. (Content is CC licensed btw)

Comment: and there is nothing relevant in `logcat`?

Comment: The problem never shows up in debug mode, so I can't check logcat (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What carrier is that? I remember that T-Mobile always routed http traffic through their own proxy which is a bit slow to refresh, and there were some issues, particularly when the data was under a certain size - 64KB, I believe.

See this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/48e84811764da1cb/7f052a903314b2b4?hl=en

Comment: Interesting... I'm on Verizon, but I'm hoping to get a friend on Sprint to try it out and possibly one on T-Mobile (I can't remember for sure which carrier he has now).

Comment: You could also try to fool the proxy by adding some dummy data to your Url, like "?randomvalue=12345678" - see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't make a difference. I finally just added a line at the end of the image downloading function that says `if(image==null) return downloadImage(url, retryCount-1);'